# devise Invalid Email or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After adding styling to the devise pages, the logins are not working.

Signup redirects to login and login says Invalid Email or password.

Here is the `sessions/new`

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="access_social">
        <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
            <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
                <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "button button--facebook button--full-width" %>
                    <% end -%>
                        <% end -%>
    </div>
    <div class="oauth__divider"><span>OR</span></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
            <br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
            <br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix mb-2">
        <div class="form-check">

            <%= f.check_box :remember_me,class: "form-check-input", as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                <label class="form-check-label">Remember me</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button button--primary button--full-width" %>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-2">
        <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
            <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %>
                <br />
                <% end -%>
    </div>

    <% end %>
```

Controllers routes and config have not been touched since changing the UI either

Comment: Please, consider to leave the old code (working code)

Comment: Could you add some logs which are generated after login action?